# Side nav is not working in materialize css

Tags: jquery, css, materialize

Sidenav is not working. I have looked on this site but couldn't find the solution I was looking for.

This is an ejs file

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Portfolio Blog</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

   <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="#" class="brand-logo center">Tech Blog</a>
      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="sass.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse show-on-large right">
          <i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
<!-- SIDENAV -->
<ul id="slide-out" class="sidenav">
   <li><div class="user-view">
     <div class="background">
       <img src="images/office.jpg">
     </div>
     <a href="#user"><img class="circle" src="images/yuna.jpg"></a>
     <a href="#email"><span class="white-text email">jdandturk@gmail.com</span></a>
   </div></li>
   <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">cloud</i>First Link With Icon</a></li>
 </ul>

    </div>
  </nav>
    <h1>Index Page</h1>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.button-collapse').sidenav();
  </script>
</html>
```

I have tried by changing the jquery to a lower version. 
If I used sideNav() instead then an error occurs:

> TypeError: $(...).sideNav is not a function

Answer (score 2):

You made some mistakes changing the code from the original snippet given by the developers. Here are the steps to fix it:

1. Change `data-activates` into `data-target`. MaterializeCss uses this `data` attribute to know to **which** sidenav the button refers to. `data-activates` doesn't mean anything to Materialize.
2. Change class of the burger menu from `button-collapse` to `sidenav-trigger`. This is the class that permits the button to **open** the navbar, you cannot use one of your liking
3. Change the target element for the initialization of the Sidenav from `$('.button-collapse')` to `$('.sidenav')`. You have to initialize the **navbar**, not the button.

---

**NOTE**: You have to click on **FULL PAGE** after running the code snippet to see it work...

This because you placed your burger menu (which is supposed to be **always visible** because of the class `show-on-large`) inside the `navbar-mobile` element (which is **hidden** on medium and small screen sizes... Isn't that **everything but mobile**? Maybe you wanted the `show-on-med-and-down` helper?).

I think you should read more carefully the docs or you'll end up confusing your code :/

Hope i didn't forgot anything :)

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Portfolio Blog</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="#" class="brand-logo center">Tech Blog</a>
      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="sass.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-target="slide-out" class="sidenav-trigger show-on-large right">
          <i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!-- SIDENAV -->
      <ul id="slide-out" class="sidenav">
        <li>
          <div class="user-view">
            <div class="background">
              <img src="images/office.jpg">
            </div>
            <a href="#user"><img class="circle" src="images/yuna.jpg"></a>
            <a href="#email"><span class="white-text email">jdandturk@gmail.com</span></a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">cloud</i>First Link With Icon</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <h1>Index Page</h1>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('.sidenav').sidenav();
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you are looking for i used jQuery 3.3.1.

Modified the sidenav trigger button like this:

```
<a href="#" data-target="slide-out" class="button-collapse sidenav-trigger show-on-large right">
   <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
</a>
```

Then i [initialized the sidenav](https://materializecss.com/sidenav.html) as the doc says:

```
$('.sidenav').sidenav();
```

and now it works.